# JLabel, how to set coodinats

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to put JLabel by using coordinates in particular place.
But instead the label appear in the middle of a top of my window.
Please tell me what I do wrong.

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

```
private Color color = Color.RED;
private GeneralPath path;
Graphics2D graphics2D;
ArrayList<PathToDraw> generalPathToDraws;



public PaintPanel() {
    path = new GeneralPath();
    ArrayList<Object> generalPathToDraws = new ArrayList<>();
    //path.moveTo(564, 278);
}

//add multiplay general pathes to drowing
public void addMultiplayPathesAndDrowThem(ArrayList<PathToDraw> ptd){

    generalPathToDraws = ptd;
    updateGraphics();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;


    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    JLabel A_label = new JLabel("B");
    A_label.setLocation(300, 300);
    A_label.setForeground(Color.red);
    add(A_label);
```

[image: how it looks]

Comment: Do *not* add a label to the frame inside the `paintComponent()` method. That method is intended for painting, not for changing structure. If you want to draw text, you can draw text, you don't need a label. If you want a label, you should add it at the point where your user requested to add it, it will be automatically painted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want use "setLocation" your panel layout should be "null"

```
public static class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    public MainPanel() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        JLabel A_label = new JLabel("B");

        A_label.setBounds(100, 100, 10, 10);//set location & size
        //Or
        //A_label.setSize(10, 10);
        //A_label.setLocation(100, 100);

        A_label.setForeground(Color.red);
        this.add(A_label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it appear where i need. But do not disappear. How can I delete old JLabels when paintComponent runs.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer of comment question.

```
static JLabel A_label;

public static class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    public MainPanel() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        A_label = new JLabel("B");
        A_label.setBounds(100, 100, 10, 10);//set location & size
        A_label.setForeground(Color.red);
        this.add(A_label);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        this.remove(A_label);
    }
}
```

Or, if you just want change text

```
static JLabel A_label;

public static class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    public MainPanel() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        A_label = new JLabel("B");
        A_label.setBounds(100, 100, 10, 10);//set location & size
        A_label.setForeground(Color.red);
        this.add(A_label);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        A_label.setText("C");
    }
}
```